# Is there WebView in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, webview, flutter

I am looking for **WebView** in flutter. How can I show my Html contents in flutter ?
Actually our books format is Html so I need WebView or a way to parse Html in flutter programming.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658910/how-to-add-a-webview-in-flutter

Comment: in pub , there is a plugin for this : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin, add it as a dependency to pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

[> flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

It is a plugin that allow `Flutter` to communicate with a native `WebView`.

**Note:** *The webview is not integrated in the widget tree, it is a native view on top of the flutter view. you won't be able to use snackbars, dialogs ...*

Answer (score 6):

A Flutter plugin that provides a [webview](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) widget is available now for Developers Preview

usage

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
        javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
```

[full code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/webview_flutter/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: is there a way to add html string to this webview widget??

Comment: @MounirElfassi, You can use `Uri.dataFromString()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149298/3681880).

Comment: this works properly on iOS but not on Android(both emulator and actual device)

Answer (score 2):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter Plugin that allows you to add **inline webviews** integrated with the widget tree or open an in-app browser window! It offers a lot of events, methods, and options compared to other webview plugins!

#### Main Classes:

- [InAppWebView](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inappwebview-class): Flutter Widget for adding an **inline native WebView** integrated into the flutter widget tree. To use `InAppWebView` class on iOS you need to opt-in for the embedded views preview by adding a boolean property to the app's `Info.plist` file, with the key `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` and the value `YES`.
- [ContextMenu](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#contextmenu-class): This class represents the WebView context menu.
- [HeadlessInAppWebView](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#headlessinappwebview-class): Class that represents a WebView in headless mode. It can be used to run a WebView in background without attaching an `InAppWebView` to the widget tree.
- [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inappbrowser-class): In-App Browser using native WebView.
- [ChromeSafariBrowser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#chromesafaribrowser-class): In-App Browser using [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/package-summary) on Android / [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) on iOS.
- [InAppLocalhostServer](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#inapplocalhostserver-class): This class allows you to create a simple server on `http://localhost:[port]/`. The default `port` value is `8080`.
- [CookieManager](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#cookiemanager-class): This class implements a singleton object (shared instance) which manages the cookies used by WebView instances.
- [HttpAuthCredentialDatabase](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#httpauthcredentialdatabase-class): This class implements a singleton object (shared instance) which manages the shared HTTP auth credentials cache.
- [WebStorageManager](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#webstoragemanager-class): This class implements a singleton object (shared instance) which manages the web storage used by WebView instances.

Quick example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Text(
                  "CURRENT URL\n${(url.length > 50) ? url.substring(0, 50) + "..." : url}"),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: progress < 1.0
                    ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                    : Container()),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                    )
                  ),
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                  },
                  onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.goBack();
                    }
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.goForward();
                    }
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (webView != null) {
                      webView.reload();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show a static html content, you can try this package: `flutter_html_view`. Flutter just supports a full-screen webview, an inline webview has not been supported yet.