# How to render a local HTML file with flutter dart webview

Tags: webview, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to render a local HTML file stored in my phone memory in webview using flutter and dart.

Comment: you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64875729/7760245

Answer (score 86):

I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) plugin from the Flutter Team.

#### Steps

1. Add the dependency to *pubspec.yaml*:

```yaml
dependencies:
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.1
```

2. Put an html file in the `assets` folder (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133627/3681880)). I'll call it `help.html`.
3. Declare it in your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/help.html
```

3. Use it in your code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HelpScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HelpScreen> createState() => _HelpScreenState();
}

class _HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = WebViewController();
    _controller.loadFlutterAsset('assets/help.html');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Notes

There are lots of other things you can do with a web view (including running JavaScript). Check out the following links for more:

- [Adding WebView to your Flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview) (official codelab)
- [Plugin example](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example)

Comment: @Suragch How do I access local js file from html in webview?
eg: `<script type="text/javascript" src="froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am facing issue, while loading a .js file

Comment: @ArnoldParge I saw that you're trying to load Froala; I'm about to try the same thing. Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: What about PDF ? How would you load a PDF ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d, You'd probably want to use a package for that. I haven't done it myself.

Comment: ```<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>``` not working

Comment: Can we use this `webview_flutter` for loading local html file in windows chrome browser

Comment: I copy+pasted this code, didnt work.

Comment: This code is out of date unfortunately.

Comment: @Andrej, I've rewritten the answer so that it is up to date again.

Answer (score 28):

You can pass a data URI

```
Uri.dataFromString('<html><body>hello world</body></html>', mimeType: 'text/html').toString()
```

or you can launch a web server inside Flutter and pass an URL that points to the IP/port the server serves the file from.

See also the discussion in https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/23

See https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets about how to load a string from assets.

See https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files for how to read other files.

Comment: encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8') would be also useful

Answer (score 17):

You may use [Flutter InAppWebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). It will create a local server inside the app and it’ll run the HTML app there in the WebView. Start your server:

```
InAppLocalhostServer localhostServer = new InAppLocalhostServer();

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await localhostServer.start();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

//... ...

class _MyHomePageState extends State < MyHomePage > {

//... ...

  @override
  void dispose() {
    localhostServer.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And then point your localhost html index file in the WebView.

```
InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/assets/index.html')),
),
```

In many cases it doesn't work for many people because they forget to add all the folders as the assets in the `pubspec.yaml` file. For example, you need to specify all the folders and index file like below:

```
  assets:
    - assets/index.html
    - assets/css/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/js/
    - assets/others/
```

You can see [this tutorial](https://blog.rimikri.com/programming/how-to-load-local-html-file-in-flutter-webview/) for further details.

Comment: Can it be done with html and css files downloaded from api? I tried, but, it only loads simple html, but no images or css. Seems like path issue, but found no solution so far.

Comment: You are my saviour!

Answer (score 14):

@Suragch, your code doesn't work as you posted it, it says `localUrl` was called on `null`.
`_loadHtmlFromAssets` needs to be called after assigning the controller :

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
  _controller = webViewController;
  _loadHtmlFromAssets();
}
```

Then it works fine :)

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem; this is how I solved it.

1. Add webview_flutter to your project dependencies:

   `webview_flutter: 0.3.14+1`
2. Create a WebViewController inside your screen/stateful widget

   `WebViewController _controller;`
3. Implement the WebView and assign a value to the _controller using the onWebViewCreated property. Load the HTML file.

```
    WebView(
        initialUrl: '',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) async {
          _controller = webViewController;
          await loadHtmlFromAssets('legal/privacy_policy.html', _controller);
        },
      )
```

4. Implement the function to load the file from the asset folder

```
    Future<void> loadHtmlFromAssets(String filename, controller) async {
        String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString(filename);
        controller.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText, mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')).toString());
    }
```

Comment: thanks but it seems to stop at this line String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString(filename);

Comment: @68060 did you declare your assets in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 6):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which has a lot of events, methods, and options compared to other plugins!

To load an html file from your assets folder, you need to declare it in the `pubspec.yaml` file before use it (see more [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#load-a-file-inside-assets-folder)).

Example of a `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
...

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/index.html

...
```

After that, you can simply use the `initialFile` parameter of the `InAppWebView` widget to load `index.html` into the WebView:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialFile: "assets/index.html",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it working with large(3-5Mb) html strings (via loadData)? Does it support inner href links (<a href="#title-page1">Title1</a>) inside these pages?

Answer (score 2):

unzip the apk package,I found the reason: path is wrong;

For Android:

`"assets/test.html" == "file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/test.html"`

so,just like this:

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: "file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/test.html",
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  )
```

you can load "assets/test.html".

Comment: Bad solution for multiplatform Flutter

Comment: Just for Android，It is useful for me

Comment: works ok on android, but for ios ?

Answer (score 1):

Use flutter_widget_from_html_core---->

link -> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html_core

```
dependencies:
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.5.1+4
```

Code like this

```
HtmlWidget(
     """
               <html lang="en">
                <body>hello world</body>
               </html>
          """,
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer, since he mentioned he wants to render a local file. Nothing about it is in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [asset_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/asset_webview) plugin is specifically designed for this. Fewer features than other plugins, but simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a proper way

```
    String webview_content = '''
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <title>Load file or HTML string example</title>
     </head>
     <body>

     <h1>Local demo page</h1>
     <p>
      This is an example page used to demonstrate how to load a local file 
      or 
      HTML 
      string using the <a 
      href="https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter">Flutter 
      webview</a> plugin.
     </p>

    </body>
    </html>
    ''';

   final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
        Completer<WebViewController>();

    Future<void> _loadHtmlString(
        Completer<WebViewController> controller, BuildContext context) async {
      WebViewController _controller = await controller.future;
      await _controller.loadHtmlString(webview_content);

    return WebView(
     initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
     onWebViewCreated:
     (WebViewController webViewController) async {
     _controller.complete(webViewController);
     _loadHtmlString(_controller, context);
},
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin in this case

1. Add webview_flutter to your dependencies

```yaml
dependencies:
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.7
```

2. Make sure to declare your HTML file as an asset in the `pubspec.yaml` file

```yaml
assets:
  - assets/index.html
```

3. Instantiate a [WebViewController](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html) and load your HTML file using [`loadFlutterAsset()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/loadFlutterAsset.html) method

```dart
final controller = WebViewController()..loadFlutterAsset('assets/index.html');
```

4. Finally pass the above instantiated `controller` to [WebViewWidget](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewWidget-class.html)

```dart
WebViewWidget(
  controller: controller
)
```

Also, in place of [`loadFlutterAsset()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/loadFlutterAsset.html) method, you can use methods like [`loadHtmlString()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/loadHtmlString.html) to load HTML from a String or [`loadFile()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController/loadFile.html) to load the HTML file located on the device (Refer [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/) for more information).

I hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I follow @Suragch answer and find that local image path in the html file cannot be loaded. So I tried a few ways and found that replacing the method `loadUrl()` with `loadFlutterAsset()` actually do the job (the code is also more simple).

```
class UserGuidePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserGuideArguments arguments;

  const UserGuidePage({required this.arguments, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserGuidePage> createState() => _UserGuidePageState();
}

class _UserGuidePageState extends State<UserGuidePage> {
  late WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'about:blank',
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller = webViewController;
      _loadHtmlFromAssets();
    },
   );
  }

  void _loadHtmlFromAssets() {
    _controller.loadFlutterAsset('assets/index.html');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the page html and use it to load the page with code below that is an example

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:aws_bot/Utils/Const.dart';
import 'package:aws_bot/Utils/User.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

class signIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const signIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _signInState createState() => _signInState();
}

class _signInState extends State<signIn> {
  String userEmail = "";
  String userPassword = "";
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  bool evalJsOnce = false;
  String _currentUrl = "";

  User _user = User();
  bool _loading = true;
  double progress = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 3), () async {
    //   Map info = await _user.getEmailPassword();
    //   _user.userEmail = info['email'];
    //   _user.userPassword = info['password'];
    //   setState(() {});
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((double progress) {
      print("progress changed = $progress");
      if (progress == 1.0) {
        //https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup
        flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
          _currentUrl = url;
          print("url changed = $url");
          if (url.contains('https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup')) {
            print("signup");
            flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
                'document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {window.Mchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-0").value, "password": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-1").value, "confirmPass": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-2").value, "accountName": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-3").value}));});');
          } else {
            flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
                'let pageHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML;'
                'window.Emailchannel.postMessage(pageHtml);'
                'if (pageHtml.includes("Root user email address")) {'
                'document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {window.Emailchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});}'
                '');
          }
          // } else if (url.contains(
          //     'https://signin.aws.amazon.com/signin?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Ffromtb%3Dtrue%26hashArgs%3D%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue%26state%3DhashArgsFromTB_us-east-1_2b2a9061808657b8&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Asignin%3A%3A%3Aconsole%2Fcanvas&forceMobileApp=0&code_challenge=-HEkj8kWzXDv2qBLcBQX2GYULvcP2gsHr0p0X_fJJcU&code_challenge_method=SHA-256')) {
          //   flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
          //       'document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault(); window.Emailchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});;');
          // } else if (url.contains(
          //     "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/signin?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Ffromtb%3Dtrue%26hashArgs%3D%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue%26state%3DhashArgsFromTB_us-east-1_c885b81ed0514ab4&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Asignin%3A%3A%3Aconsole%2Fcanvas&forceMobileApp=0&code_challenge=_Tqr3pEXTDAqOYjWp0ehE6ToYYSN7OLeyJWBx5HTPVM&code_challenge_method=SHA-256")) {
          //   print("enter pass");
          //   // flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
          //   //     'document.querySelector("#signin_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault(); window.Passwordchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"password": document.querySelector("#password").value}));});;');
          // } else if (url.contains("https://console.aws.amazon.com/")) {
          //   // flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(_consts.successDirectUrl +
          //   //     "email=${_user.userEmail}&password=${_user.userPassword}");
          // }
        });
      }
    });

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      print("state changed = $state");
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'AWS Sign In',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[600],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _backButton(context),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          (progress != 1.0)
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  // minHeight: 10.0,
                  value: progress,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black))
              : Container(),
          Container(
              color: Colors.yellow[600],
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Email Address of you AWS : ${consts.user.userEmail}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "IAM user name : ${consts.user.accountName}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Password : ${consts.user.userPassword != "null" && consts.user.userPassword != "" ? consts.user.userPassword.replaceAll(consts.user.userPassword, "******") : ""}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
          Expanded(child: _buildSignInPage()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildSignInPage() {
    String _url = "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users";
    return InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(_url)),
      // javascriptChannels: Set.from([
      //   JavascriptChannel(
      //       name: 'Emailchannel',
      //       onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
      //         //This is where you receive message from
      //         //javascript code and handle in Flutter/Dart
      //         //like here, the message is just being printed
      //         //in Run/LogCat window of android studio
      //         print("console message = ${message.message}");
      //         setState(() {
      //           _user.userEmail =
      //               jsonDecode(message.message)['email'].toString();
      //         });
      //       }),
      //   JavascriptChannel(
      //       name: 'Passwordchannel',
      //       onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
      //         //This is where you receive message from
      //         //javascript code and handle in Flutter/Dart
      //         //like here, the message is just being printed
      //         //in Run/LogCat window of android studio
      //         print("console message = ${jsonDecode(message.message)}");
      //         setState(() {
      //           _user.userEmail =
      //               jsonDecode(message.message)['password'].toString();
      //         });
      //       })
      // ]),
      // withJavascript: true,
      onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) async {
        print("console message = ${consoleMessage.message}");
        print(consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString());
        // LOG ERROR => message levels
        if (consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString() != "ERROR" &&
            consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString() != "WARNING") {
          Map message = jsonDecode(consoleMessage.message);
          if (message.containsKey("email")) {
            consts.user.userEmail = message['email'].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(email: consts.user.userEmail);
          } else if (message.containsKey("password")) {
            consts.user.userPassword = message['password'].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(password: consts.user.userPassword);
          } else if (message.containsKey("delete")) {
            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
              await consts.user.clearStorage();
              consts.user.userEmail = "";
              consts.user.userPassword = "";
            });
          } else if (message.containsKey("sEmail")) {
            consts.user.userEmail = message['sEmail'].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(email: consts.user.userEmail);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPassword")) {
            consts.user.userPassword = message["sPassword"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(password: consts.user.userPassword);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sAccountName")) {
            consts.user.accountName = message["sAccountName"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(accountName: consts.user.accountName);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sFullName")) {
            consts.user.fullName = message["sFullName"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(fullName: consts.user.fullName);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPhone")) {
            consts.user.phoneNumber = message["sPhone"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(phoneNumber: consts.user.phoneNumber);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sRegion")) {
            consts.user.region = message["sRegion"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(region: consts.user.region);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sAddress")) {
            consts.user.address = message["sAddress"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(address: consts.user.address);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sCity")) {
            consts.user.city = message["sCity"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(city: consts.user.city);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sState")) {
            consts.user.state = message["sState"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(state: consts.user.state);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPostal")) {
            consts.user.postalCode = message["sPostal"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(postalCode: consts.user.postalCode);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sOrganize")) {
            consts.user.oraganization = message["sOrganize"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(organization: consts.user.oraganization);
          }

          setState(() {
            if (consts.user.userPassword != "" &&
                !message.containsKey("delete")) {
              /*Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
                await consts.user.storeEmailAndPassword(
                    consts.user.userEmail, consts.user.userPassword);
                // controller.loadUrl(
                //     urlRequest: URLRequest(
                //         url: Uri.parse(_consts.successDirectUrl +
                //             "email=${_user.userEmail}&password=${_user.userPassword}")));
              });*/
            }
          });
        }
      },
      onWindowFocus: (controller) async {
        var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();
        final html = await controller.getHtml();
        var document = parse(html);
        if (currentUrl != _currentUrl) {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
            var htmlCode = await controller.getHtml();
            var document = parse(htmlCode);
            var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();
            print("currentUrl = ${currentUrl}");
            if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("username@example.com")) {
              print("get email");
              await consts.user.clearStorage();

              // get entered email address
              getUserEmail(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("Root user sign in")) {
              print("get pass");
              // get entered password
              getUserPassword(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (currentUrl
                .toString()
                .contains("https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup")) {
              if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("AWS account name")) {
                print("sign up");
                // get signUp email
                getSignUpEmail(controller);
                // get signUp password
                getSignUpPassword(controller);
                // get signUp account name
                getSignUpAccountName(controller);
              } else if (document.body!.innerHtml
                  .contains("Contact Information")) {
                // get full name
                getSignUpFullname(controller);
                // get phone number
                getSignUpPhoneNumber(controller);
                // get region
                getSignUpRegion(controller);
                // get address
                getSignUpAddress(controller);
                // get city
                getSignUpCity(controller);
                // get state
                getSignUpState(controller);
                // get postal code
                getSignUpPostalCode(controller);
                // get organization
                getSignUpOrganization(controller);
              }
            }
          });
        }
        _currentUrl = currentUrl.toString();
        //controller.goBack();
      },
      onProgressChanged:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) async {
        setState(() {
          this.progress = progress / 100;
          print("progress = ${this.progress}");
        });
        if (progress == 100) {
          var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();

          Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 3), () async {
            var htmlCode = await controller.getHtml();
            var document = parse(htmlCode);

            print("currentUrl progress = ${currentUrl.toString()}");
            //print("html = ${document.body!.innerHtml}");
            if (document.body!.innerHtml
                .contains("Email address of your AWS account")) {
              print("get email");
              await consts.user.clearStorage();
              consts.user.userEmail = "";
              consts.user.userPassword = "";
              controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
                   document.querySelector("#new_account_container").style.display = "none";
            """);
              setState(() {});

              // get entered email address
              getUserEmail(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("Root user sign in")) {
              print("get pass");
              // get entered password
              getUserPassword(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (currentUrl
                .toString()
                .contains("https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup#/")) {
              if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("AWS account name")) {
                print("sign up progress");
                // get signUp email
                getSignUpEmail(controller);
                // get signUp password
                getSignUpPassword(controller);
                // get signUp account name
                getSignUpAccountName(controller);
              } else if (document.body!.innerHtml
                  .contains("Contact Information")) {
                // get full name
                getSignUpFullname(controller);
                // get phone number
                getSignUpPhoneNumber(controller);
                // get region
                getSignUpRegion(controller);
                // get address
                getSignUpAddress(controller);
                // get city
                getSignUpCity(controller);
                // get state
                getSignUpState(controller);
                // get postal code
                getSignUpPostalCode(controller);
                // get organization
                getSignUpOrganization(controller);
              }
            }
            if (currentUrl.toString() ==
                    "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users" ||
                currentUrl.toString() ==
                    "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users") {
              print("delete credentials");
              // delete user data if loged out
              deleteCredentials(controller);
            }
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // get user amil
  getUserEmail(InAppWebViewController controller, String html) {
    controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
        handlerName: 'EmailGetter',
        callback: (args) {
          // print arguments coming from the JavaScript side!
          print("email args = $args");
          // return data to the JavaScript side!
          return args;
        });
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting password
  getUserPassword(InAppWebViewController controller, String html) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#signin_button").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"password": document.querySelector("#password").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp Email address
  getSignUpEmail(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sEmail": document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp password
  getSignUpPassword(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPassword": document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp account name
  getSignUpAccountName(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sAccountName": document.querySelector("input[name='accountName']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp fullName
  getSignUpFullname(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sFullName": document.querySelector("input[name='address.fullName']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp phone number
  getSignUpPhoneNumber(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPhone": document.querySelector("input[name='address.phoneNumber']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp region
  getSignUpRegion(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sRegion": document.querySelectorAll(".awsui-select-trigger-label")[1].innerText}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp address
  getSignUpAddress(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sAddress": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.addressLine1']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp city
  getSignUpCity(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sCity": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.city']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp state
  getSignUpState(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sState": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.state']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp postal code
  getSignUpPostalCode(controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPostal": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.postalCode']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp organization
  getSignUpOrganization(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sOrganize": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.company']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // deleting user credentials
  deleteCredentials(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#aws-console-logout").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"delete": "delete"}));});
            """);
  }

  _backButton(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should remove the comments and maybe split your code in more logical blocks

Answer (score -1):

Here is much more cleaner code of above code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:aws_bot/Utils/Const.dart';
import 'package:aws_bot/Utils/User.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

class signIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const signIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _signInState createState() => _signInState();
}

class _signInState extends State<signIn> {
  String userEmail = "";
  String userPassword = "";
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  bool evalJsOnce = false;
  String _currentUrl = "";

  User _user = User();
  bool _loading = true;
  double progress = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((double progress) {
      print("progress changed = $progress");
      if (progress == 1.0) {
        //https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup
        flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
          _currentUrl = url;
          print("url changed = $url");
          if (url.contains('https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup')) {
            print("signup");
            flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
                'document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {window.Mchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-0").value, "password": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-1").value, "confirmPass": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-2").value, "accountName": document.querySelector("#awsui-input-3").value}));});');
          } else {
            flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(''
                'let pageHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML;'
                'window.Emailchannel.postMessage(pageHtml);'
                'if (pageHtml.includes("Root user email address")) {'
                'document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {window.Emailchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});}'
                '');
          }
          redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Ffromtb%3Dtrue%26hashArgs%3D%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue%26state%3DhashArgsFromTB_us-east-1_2b2a9061808657b8&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Asignin%3A%3A%3Aconsole%2Fcanvas&forceMobileApp=0&code_challenge=-HEkj8kWzXDv2qBLcBQX2GYULvcP2gsHr0p0X_fJJcU&code_challenge_method=SHA-256')) {  'document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault(); window.Emailchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});;');redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Ffromtb%3Dtrue%26hashArgs%3D%2523%26isauthcode%3Dtrue%26state%3DhashArgsFromTB_us-east-1_c885b81ed0514ab4&client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Asignin%3A%3A%3Aconsole%2Fcanvas&forceMobileApp=0&code_challenge=_Tqr3pEXTDAqOYjWp0ehE6ToYYSN7OLeyJWBx5HTPVM&code_challenge_method=SHA-256")) {   'document.querySelector("#signin_button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault(); window.Passwordchannel.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"password": document.querySelector("#password").value}));});;');
        });
      }
    });

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
      print("state changed = $state");
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'AWS Sign In',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[600],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _backButton(context),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          (progress != 1.0)
              ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                  // minHeight: 10.0,
                  value: progress,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black))
              : Container(),
          Container(
              color: Colors.yellow[600],
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Email Address of you AWS : ${consts.user.userEmail}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "IAM user name : ${consts.user.accountName}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Password : ${consts.user.userPassword != "null" && consts.user.userPassword != "" ? consts.user.userPassword.replaceAll(consts.user.userPassword, "******") : ""}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
          Expanded(child: _buildSignInPage()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildSignInPage() {
    String _url = "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users";
    return InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(_url)),
      onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) async {
        print("console message = ${consoleMessage.message}");
        print(consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString());
        // LOG ERROR => message levels
        if (consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString() != "ERROR" &&
            consoleMessage.messageLevel.toString() != "WARNING") {
          Map message = jsonDecode(consoleMessage.message);
          if (message.containsKey("email")) {
            consts.user.userEmail = message['email'].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(email: consts.user.userEmail);
          } else if (message.containsKey("password")) {
            consts.user.userPassword = message['password'].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(password: consts.user.userPassword);
          } else if (message.containsKey("delete")) {
            Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
              await consts.user.clearStorage();
              consts.user.userEmail = "";
              consts.user.userPassword = "";
            });
          } else if (message.containsKey("sEmail")) {
            consts.user.userEmail = message['sEmail'].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(email: consts.user.userEmail);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPassword")) {
            consts.user.userPassword = message["sPassword"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(password: consts.user.userPassword);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sAccountName")) {
            consts.user.accountName = message["sAccountName"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(accountName: consts.user.accountName);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sFullName")) {
            consts.user.fullName = message["sFullName"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(fullName: consts.user.fullName);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPhone")) {
            consts.user.phoneNumber = message["sPhone"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(phoneNumber: consts.user.phoneNumber);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sRegion")) {
            consts.user.region = message["sRegion"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(region: consts.user.region);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sAddress")) {
            consts.user.address = message["sAddress"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(address: consts.user.address);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sCity")) {
            consts.user.city = message["sCity"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(city: consts.user.city);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sState")) {
            consts.user.state = message["sState"].toString();
            await consts.user.storeSignUpInfo(state: consts.user.state);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sPostal")) {
            consts.user.postalCode = message["sPostal"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(postalCode: consts.user.postalCode);
          } else if (message.containsKey("sOrganize")) {
            consts.user.oraganization = message["sOrganize"].toString();
            await consts.user
                .storeSignUpInfo(organization: consts.user.oraganization);
          }

          setState(() {
            if (consts.user.userPassword != "" &&
                !message.containsKey("delete")) {
            }
          });
        }
      },
      onWindowFocus: (controller) async {
        var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();
        final html = await controller.getHtml();
        var document = parse(html);
        if (currentUrl != _currentUrl) {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
            var htmlCode = await controller.getHtml();
            var document = parse(htmlCode);
            var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();
            print("currentUrl = ${currentUrl}");
            if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("username@example.com")) {
              print("get email");
              await consts.user.clearStorage();

              // get entered email address
              getUserEmail(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("Root user sign in")) {
              print("get pass");
              // get entered password
              getUserPassword(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (currentUrl
                .toString()
                .contains("https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup")) {
              if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("AWS account name")) {
                print("sign up");
                // get signUp email
                getSignUpEmail(controller);
                // get signUp password
                getSignUpPassword(controller);
                // get signUp account name
                getSignUpAccountName(controller);
              } else if (document.body!.innerHtml
                  .contains("Contact Information")) {
                // get full name
                getSignUpFullname(controller);
                // get phone number
                getSignUpPhoneNumber(controller);
                // get region
                getSignUpRegion(controller);
                // get address
                getSignUpAddress(controller);
                // get city
                getSignUpCity(controller);
                // get state
                getSignUpState(controller);
                // get postal code
                getSignUpPostalCode(controller);
                // get organization
                getSignUpOrganization(controller);
              }
            }
          });
        }
        _currentUrl = currentUrl.toString();
        //controller.goBack();
      },
      onProgressChanged:
          (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) async {
        setState(() {
          this.progress = progress / 100;
          print("progress = ${this.progress}");
        });
        if (progress == 100) {
          var currentUrl = await controller.getUrl();

          Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 3), () async {
            var htmlCode = await controller.getHtml();
            var document = parse(htmlCode);

            print("currentUrl progress = ${currentUrl.toString()}");
            //print("html = ${document.body!.innerHtml}");
            if (document.body!.innerHtml
                .contains("Email address of your AWS account")) {
              print("get email");
              await consts.user.clearStorage();
              consts.user.userEmail = "";
              consts.user.userPassword = "";
              controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
                   document.querySelector("#new_account_container").style.display = "none";
            """);
              setState(() {});

              // get entered email address
              getUserEmail(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("Root user sign in")) {
              print("get pass");
              // get entered password
              getUserPassword(controller, document.body!.innerHtml);
            } else if (currentUrl
                .toString()
                .contains("https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup#/")) {
              if (document.body!.innerHtml.contains("AWS account name")) {
                print("sign up progress");
                // get signUp email
                getSignUpEmail(controller);
                // get signUp password
                getSignUpPassword(controller);
                // get signUp account name
                getSignUpAccountName(controller);
              } else if (document.body!.innerHtml
                  .contains("Contact Information")) {
                // get full name
                getSignUpFullname(controller);
                // get phone number
                getSignUpPhoneNumber(controller);
                // get region
                getSignUpRegion(controller);
                // get address
                getSignUpAddress(controller);
                // get city
                getSignUpCity(controller);
                // get state
                getSignUpState(controller);
                // get postal code
                getSignUpPostalCode(controller);
                // get organization
                getSignUpOrganization(controller);
              }
            }
            if (currentUrl.toString() ==
                    "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users" ||
                currentUrl.toString() ==
                    "https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/users") {
              print("delete credentials");
              // delete user data if loged out
              deleteCredentials(controller);
            }
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // get user amil
  getUserEmail(InAppWebViewController controller, String html) {
    controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
        handlerName: 'EmailGetter',
        callback: (args) {
          // print arguments coming from the JavaScript side!
          print("email args = $args");
          // return data to the JavaScript side!
          return args;
        });
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#next_button").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"email": document.querySelector("#resolving_input").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting password
  getUserPassword(InAppWebViewController controller, String html) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#signin_button").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"password": document.querySelector("#password").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp Email address
  getSignUpEmail(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sEmail": document.querySelector("input[name='email']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp password
  getSignUpPassword(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPassword": document.querySelector("input[name='password']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp account name
  getSignUpAccountName(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#CredentialCollection").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sAccountName": document.querySelector("input[name='accountName']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp fullName
  getSignUpFullname(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sFullName": document.querySelector("input[name='address.fullName']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp phone number
  getSignUpPhoneNumber(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPhone": document.querySelector("input[name='address.phoneNumber']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp region
  getSignUpRegion(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sRegion": document.querySelectorAll(".awsui-select-trigger-label")[1].innerText}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp address
  getSignUpAddress(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sAddress": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.addressLine1']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp city
  getSignUpCity(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sCity": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.city']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp state
  getSignUpState(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sState": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.state']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp postal code
  getSignUpPostalCode(controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sPostal": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.postalCode']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // getting SignUp organization
  getSignUpOrganization(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#ContactInformation").addEventListener("submit", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"sOrganize": document.querySelectorAll("input[name='address.company']").value}));});
            """);
  }

  // deleting user credentials
  deleteCredentials(InAppWebViewController controller) {
    controller.evaluateJavascript(source: """
            document.querySelector("#aws-console-logout").addEventListener("click", function(ee) {
            window.console.log(JSON.stringify({"delete": "delete"}));});
            """);
  }

  _backButton(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    );
  }
}
```

In this code you can see also how to use javascript dom manipulation and selection and interaction with web page.