# How to specify the encoding for a dart Uri in a Flutter project

Tags: webview, dart, flutter, uri

I am trying to display some static html in an app using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.

```
body: WebView(
  initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
      htmlString, 
      mimeType: 'text/html', 
      encoding: Encoding('utf-8')
  ).toString(),
),
```

I was getting an error about an invalid character error, and I assumed that is because Uri defaults to ASCII. I am trying to set the character encoding to UTF-8 but I can't figure out how to do it. `Encoding('utf-8')` is obviously not right.

How do I set the encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the encoding like this:

```
Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
```

See also [How to render a local HTML file in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149298/3681880)

Answer (score 1):

Safe Url Encoding in flutter
Ex.

```
String url  = 'http://example.org/';
String postDataKey = "requestParam="
String postData = 'hdfhghdf+fdfbjdfjjndf'
```

In Case of get request :

```
Uri.encodeComponent(url+postDataKey+postData);
```

In Case of Post Data Request use **[flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)** library

```
var data = postDataKey + Uri.encodeComponent(postData);
webViewController.postUrl(url: Uri.parse(url), postData: utf8.encode(data));
```

Comment: Still it replace `+` with space. Can you please help?