# Flutter Webview change webpage is not available

Tags: android, webview, dart, flutter, android-webview

I wanna change the "Webpage not available", in my WebView application, if the user doesn't have internet.

I read the documentation, and try some another puglins

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
[...]
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can render a local `html` file when there's no connection as showed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview

Comment: I ve try this, and the Medium post to, but doesnt have the error handiling, showing the screen WebPage not avaiable

Comment: I chance the plugin and use url_launcher, encapsuled with try catch block statement, solving the problem

Comment: glad to hear that !

Answer (score 6):

Just Add **onWebResourceError** method to your Webview.

```
    WebView(
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError webviewerrr) {
            print("Handle your Error Page here");
        },
        initialUrl: "your url"
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading:');
        },
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview). It has events to manage errors while the WebView is loading an url (`onLoadError` event) and when it receives HTTP errors, such as 403, 404, etc (`onLoadHttpError` event).

Full example with working code that loads a custom error page if the user doesn't have internet connection:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                        inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, int code, String message) async {
                      print("error $url: $code, $message");

                      var tRexHtml = await controller.getTRexRunnerHtml();
                      var tRexCss = await controller.getTRexRunnerCss();

                      controller.loadData(data: """
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style>$tRexCss</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    $tRexHtml
    <p>
      URL $url failed to load.
    </p>
    <p>
      Error: $code, $message
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
                  """);
                    },
                    onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, int statusCode, String description) async {
                      print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

This example loads directly an html source, but you can load an html file from the assets folder or an url.

Just for fun: my plugin includes the javascript and css code of the Google Chrome t-rex game!

Comment: using a plugin to fix something isn't a solution ! either explain how your plugin solves the problem or just add a comment...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested previously [InAppWebView](https://inappwebview.dev/) has great support. Implementation suggested above is a bit outdated. Here is updated implementation which loads HTML string into view on page load error (timeout). This is tested and works with latest version of plugin and Android 14.

I have not included any other methods handling but here is full implementation
which works.

```dart
body: Container(
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev/",
            initialHeaders: {},
             initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                transparentBackground: true,
              ),
              android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                useHybridComposition: true, // makes scrolling smooth on Android
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              // do something with the controller if needed
            },
            onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
              // Show loading indicator etc
            },
            onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
              // Hide loading indicator etc
            },
            onLoadHttpError: (controller, url, statusCode, description) {
                print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
            },
            onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
              print("error $url: $code, $message");
              controller.loadData(data: """
                  <html>
                    <head>
                      <meta charset="utf-8">
                      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
                      <style></style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <p style="color: #ef7174; text-align: center; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px; background-color: #fce3e3; border-radius: 30px; margin-top: 40% margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                        Page not found or there is no internet connection.
                      </p>
                    </body>
                  </html>
              """);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ]))
```