# How to render partial content of a website in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am new to Flutter and I would like to render a partial content from a website in my Flutter application. Imagine this as an example: I want to render the main content of this website: https://flutter.dev/. I could obtain this content by executing the javascript command: `document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0]` .

What do I have to do to display this content in an WebView inside my Flutter application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[This answer demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149298/85472) how to pass html content to a Webview plugin in Flutter.
In your case you dont need to read from a file as in that answer, just pass in the String that you obtain from whatever means you need to use.

The relevant part of that answers code for you is:

```dart
 String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/help.html');
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
```

where in your case the `fileText` String is the html content that you got from somewhere.