# Flutter: How show local html file in webview?

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I use this plugin in my flutter app - [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#-installing-tab-). I need to show the local HTML file in webview. This is not from assets, but I have a path to this file.
I try it:

1. Read the file as a string

   ```
   var file = File(_path);
   var data = await file.readAsString();
   ```
2. prepare the string

   ```
   String _getHtml() { 
      var html = Uri.dataFromString(data, mimeType: 'text/html').toString();
      return html;
   }
   ```
3. Show this string in my webview

   ```
   WebView(
      initialUrl: _getHtml(),
   )
   ```

But I have get error(on step Uri.dataFromString) :

[image]

How fix it? Any tips?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a local HTML file with flutter dart webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HelpScreenState createState() {
    return HelpScreenState();
  }
}

class HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await 
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/help.html');
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```