# How do I copy a web page including html tags to a Flutter app?

Tags: html, flutter, clipboard

If I select part of a web page (like in the attached picture) and copy it to Microsoft Word, almost all the information will be displayed including the title, hyperlink, and image.

But if I paste it to the Flutter app, only plain text is displayed.
So my question is how to copy those HTML tags to the Flutter app?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a local HTML file with flutter dart webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview)

Comment: unfortunately no. I need to get those html text first. what I get now from clipboard is plain text.

Comment: _why_ would you want to do this? It's impossible unless you manually parse your html to widgets with `dart:html`

Comment: A user might want to copy some content from internet and post to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_html package, you can find it on the this link =>
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html
and this is how you can use it

```
 Future<void> showPrivacyPolicy(BuildContext context) async {
   return showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isDismissible: true,
    builder: (context) => Material(
      child: Column(
       children: [
         AppBar(
           title: Text(
            'PRIVACY POLICY',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
           ),
           centerTitle: true,
           backgroundColor: ceruleanTwo,
           elevation: 0,
         ),
         Expanded(
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Html(
               data: privacyString,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
    ),
   );
 }
```