# How to resolve "Non-nullable instance field '_controller' must be initialized" error in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I need to open a local HTML file, for which I am trying to use the following code:

```dart
class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HelpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HelpScreen> createState() => _HelpScreenState();
}

class _HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Privacy Policy.html');
    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```

I have met it several times on the Internet. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831312/how-to-render-a-local-html-file-with-flutter-dart-webview).

But when I try to use it I get an error:

```dart
Non-nullable instance field '_controller' must be initialized. (Documentation) Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.
```

_controller is highlighted in red and prevents the application from starting. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `WebViewController` is non-nullable, you'll need to initialize it, like at the time of declaration or in the constructor initializing formals. But I can see you are initializing at a later stage. So, it's better to use `late`.

Change

```dart
WebViewController _controller;
```

to

```dart
late WebViewController _controller;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `late` keyword since you're initializing `_controller` later on:

```dart
class _HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  late WebViewController _controller;
```