# Does anyone know how to make an http request in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to make an app in which the user needs to press an InkWell or a button and then it should take them to a website, so does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Webview in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658910/how-to-add-a-webview-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really nice plugin for this, called ***[`url_launcher`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)***. *Usage* is as follows:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => launch(websiteUrl),
  ...
)
```

You can also use `canLaunch` to test if launching will work. More on that [in `README.md`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/url_launcher/README.md).