# Flutter || WebView configuration in IOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I finished my WebView project for android and I want to make it work for IOS too. I have no idea how to do configuration in XCODE to make it work for IOS system. I didn't find any resource in any platform. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

can be a reference material

[How to add a Webview in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658910/how-to-add-a-webview-in-flutter)

already set on info.plist ?

```html
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key><string>yes</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: It's the only configuration and it work perfectly ??

Answer (score 0):

If your web-view is not loading you have to Add this to your Info.plist. This is only configuration required for IOS and only for http url.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```