# How to implement web view in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview, mobile-application

I am developing an app in Flutter and need to implement a web view. But don't know how to implement it. Can anyone suggest to me any good library for it? I tried '**webview_flutter**', but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a Webview in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658910/how-to-add-a-webview-in-flutter)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658910/how-to-add-a-webview-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will work for you but you can try inappwebview:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 0):

If I put it simply

**1. flutter_inappwebview (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)**

> - Scalability: Excellent
> - User-friendliness: Natural
> - JavaScript usability: Available (only for normal classes)
> - Ability to open a new window: Available
> - Ability to share via email, SNS, or phone: Unavailable

**2. url_launcher (https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)**

> - Scalability: Medium
> - User-friendliness: Slightly unnatural
> - JavaScript usability: Unavailable
> - Ability to open a new window: Available
> - Ability to share via email, SNS, or phone: Available

**3. webview_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)**

> - Scalability: Low
> - User-friendliness: Medium
> - JavaScript usability: Available
> - Ability to open a new window: Unavailable
> - Ability to share via email, SNS, or phone: Unavailable

I hope this helps if there are any mistranslations or mistakes.